# Finding Jaccard Similarity according to a threshold python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to take rows which have a jaccard similarity score between a threshold.
I have a file like this with lots of rows:

| id | animals |
| --- | --- |
| a | dog, cat, fish |
| b | cat, fish |
| c | dog, bird, fish |
| d | dog |

The code that I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'letters': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'animals': ['dog, cat, fish', 'cat, fish', 'dog, bird, fish', 'dog']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def jaccard(list1, list2):
    intersection = len(list(set(list1).intersection(list2)))
    union = (len(list1) + len(list2)) - intersection
    return float(intersection) / union

out_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['letters', 'animals', 'sub-animal-letters'])

for ind1, r1 in df.iterrows():
    sim = []
    for ind2, r2 in df.iterrows():
        sim.append(jaccard(r1['animals'].split(','), r2['animals'].split(',')))
    inds = [i for i, x in enumerate(sim) if x <= 0.4 and x > 0.3]

    out_data = pd.concat([out_data, pd.DataFrame(
            [[r1['letters'], r1['animals'], ','.join([str(df.iloc[i]['letters']) for i in inds])]], 
        columns=['letters', 'animals', 'sub-animal-letters'])])

print(out_data)
```

and the output should be like this because similarity threshold is between 0.4 and 0.3:

| id | animals | sub-animal-letters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | dog, cat, fish | d |
| c | dog, bird, fish | d |

But when I run this code I get:

| id | animals | sub-animal-letters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | dog, cat, fish | d |
| b | cat, fish |  |
| c | dog, bird, fish | d |
| d | dog | a,c |

Also when I try to get similarity score bigger than 0.95 then it also returns itsel as sub-animals-letters, but I dont want this. It should return sub letters except itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to compute the pairs to evaluate:

```
from itertools import combinations

lsts = df['animals'].str.split(r',\s*')

keep = (pd.Series({(a, b): df.loc[b, 'letters']
                    for a, b in combinations(lsts.index, r=2)
                    if 0.3 < jaccard(lsts[a], lsts[b]) <= 0.4
                   })
          .groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
        )

out = df.loc[keep.index].join(keep.rename('sub-animal-letters'))
```

Output:

```
  letters          animals sub-animal-letters
0       a   dog, cat, fish                  d
2       c  dog, bird, fish                  d
```

##### with scores:

```
from itertools import combinations

lsts = df['animals'].str.split(r',\s*')

keep = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
           {(a, b):{'sub-animal-letters': df.loc[b, 'letters'],
                    'score': j}
                    for a, b in combinations(lsts.index, r=2)
                    if 0.3 < (j:=jaccard(lsts[a], lsts[b])) <= 0.4
                   }, orient='index')
          .groupby(level=0).agg({'sub-animal-letters': ', '.join,
                                 'score': list
                                })
        )

out = df.loc[keep.index].join(keep)
```

Output:

```
  letters          animals sub-animal-letters                 score
0       a   dog, cat, fish                  d  [0.3333333333333333]
2       c  dog, bird, fish                  d  [0.3333333333333333]
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. If I want to make changes on my own code. Do you have an idea about what should I do?

Comment: Or If I want to add a new jaccard score column for each sub-animal-letters, what should I do?

Comment: See the update, regarding your original code I really recommend not to use `iterrows`